# I'm trying to show that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$, is my argument ok?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Here is my try:

We know that $\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0} y = 0$, so define $y=\frac{1}{x}$, then:

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x} = \lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y}}= \lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0} 1 \frac{y}{1}=\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0} y = 0$

Is my argument correct? I don't know if it's right or wrong.

If it's ok, how do I justify each step?

If it's wrong, which step is illegal?

Thanks.

Comment: Your argument becomes circular in the first step; you assume that lim(x to infinity) 1/x is zero while trying to prove exactly that.

Comment: How do you know $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x =\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac 1y $?

Comment: @fleablood it's an example in my textbook

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I don't see exactly where, can you post and answer explaining this?

Comment: As y > 0, then, yes, lim 1/x = lim 1/lim x = lim 1/lim 1/y =lim 1/1/y= lim y.

Answer (score 1):

There is something  wrong in the second step. You define $y=\frac 1x$, but how do you know that $y\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, which is needed to prove, however you has used the result.